# Submit contact form to wordpress database

Tags: php, database, forms, wordpress

I have the following code, which is supposed to create a form on the page, and when I submit it it should connect to the database and add the date and form info to wp_user_feedback. Currently the form doesn't even show up on the page not sure why?

NEW ERROR:

> ```
> Notice: Undefined index: responseFields in /Users/anderskitson/Sites/fiftyfity/wp-content/themes/fiftyfityNew/contact-form
> ```
>
> copy.php on line 33

```
<?php function make_user_feedback_form() {
    global $wpdb;
    global $current_user;


        $ufUserID = $current_user->ID;
        $ufResponses = serialize($_POST["responseFields"]);
        if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'updateFeedback' ) {
            $ufDataUpdate = $wpdb->insert( 'wp_user_feedback', array( 'date' => current_time('mysql'), 'responses' => $ufResponses ) );
        }?>
    <ol>
        <form method="post">
            <li>Question 01<br /><input type="text" id="responseFields[]" value="" /></li>
            <li>Question 02<br /><input type="text" id="responseFields[]" value="" /></li>
            <li><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit button" value="Send feedback" /></li>
            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'updateFeedback' ); ?>
            <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="updateFeedback" />
        </form>
    </ol>
    <?php 
}

add_action('the_content','make_user_feedback_form');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the form in the function. Are you calling the function anywhere?

If you didn't intend it to be part of the function, move the last `}` above the opening `<ol>`

So, it should look like this (if pulling it out of the function)

```
<?php function make_user_feedback_form() {
 global $wpdb;
global $current_user;


    $ufUserID = $current_user->ID;
    $ufResponses = serialize($_POST["responseFields"]);
    if ( 'POST' == $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && !empty( $_POST['action'] ) && $_POST['action'] == 'updateFeedback' ) {
        $ufDataUpdate = $wpdb->insert( 'wp_user_feedback', array( 'date' => current_time('mysql'), 'responses' => $ufResponses ) );
        }
    }
    ?>
<ol>
    <form method="post">
        <li>Question 01<br /><input type="text" id="responseFields[]" value="" /></li>
        <li>Question 02<br /><input type="text" id="responseFields[]" value="" /></li>
        <li><input name="submit" type="submit" id="submit" class="submit button" value="Send feedback" /></li>
        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'updateFeedback' ); ?>
        <input name="action" type="hidden" id="action" value="updateFeedback" />
    </form>
</ol>
<?php 
    add_action('the_content','make_user_feedback_form');
?>
```

Comment: I think he intends to put the form inside the function. Where do you add this piece of code to, Anders ?

Comment: I moved the } and called the function with <?php make_user_feedback_form();?> however I get a error, which I added above.

Comment: Don't move the `}` if you intend the form to be inside the function. My example is ONLY if you wanted it outside the function

Comment: Thanks! The form is showing now, however; I am getting a new error below it not sure what it means, I have posted it above.